# Finding Determinant of NxN matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

I tried to solve a matrix question for hours, I made lots of calculations for finding determinant of it. However, I could not solve the problem. Here is that matrix;

$$A =\begin{bmatrix}x+a_1 & a_2 & a_3 & ... & a_n\\ a_1& x+a_2 &a_3&...&a_n\\ a_1& a_2 &x+a_3&...&a_n\\...& ... &...&...&...\\a_1& a_2 &a_3&...&x+a_n\end{bmatrix}$$
Find $|A|$ = ?

Comment: Do you know what row operations do to the determinant?  What happens if you subtract the last row from each preceding row?